# %a and %%a suddenly don't work in Win 10 cmd and batch file respectively?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I was trying to batch convert a folder of .flac to .mp3 using FFMPEG, but when i ran my batch file I got the "%F is unexpected at this time" error, even though i used "%%F" in the batch file. To test what was really the problem, i proceeded to type variations of %F into cmd directly, but could not get it to work either. Did something change in windows 10 regarding the use of variable names in the for loop?

cmd commands I tried:

```
C:\Users\yt\Music\Joe Hisaishi (Classical Guitar) - Copy>for "%F" in     (*.flac) echo %F
"%F" was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\yt\Music\Joe Hisaishi (Classical Guitar) - Copy>for %F in     (*.flac) echo %F
echo was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\yt\Music\Joe Hisaishi (Classical Guitar) - Copy>for "%%F" in     (*.flac) echo %%F
"%%F" was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\yt\Music\Joe Hisaishi (Classical Guitar) - Copy>for "%f" in     (*.flac) echo %f
"%f" was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\yt\Music\Joe Hisaishi (Classical Guitar) - Copy>for "%g" in     (*.flac) echo %g
"%g" was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\yt\Music\Joe Hisaishi (Classical Guitar) - Copy>for "%g" in     ("*.*") echo %g
"%g" was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\yt\Music\Joe Hisaishi (Classical Guitar) - Copy>for "%g" in     ("*.*") do echo %g
"%g" was unexpected at this time.
```

original batch file for FFMPEG

```
cd "\Users\yt\Music\Joe Hisaishi (Classical Guitar) - Copy"
echo in directory "%cd%"
pause
for "%%F" in ("*.flac") do (
echo converting "%%F"
"C:\Users\yt\Downloads\OtherApps\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%F"     -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 "%%~nF.mp3"
echo del "%%F"
)
cd "%~dp0"
```

Comment: Besides the fact that the quotes around the `for` variable reference (`"%F"`, `"%%F"`) must be removed, there is the keyword `do` missing in almost all of your examples...

Comment: You didn't declare a for type.... `for /F` (read) or `for /L` (loop)

Comment: @GhostBladez, the [`for` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) can also be used without any switch, so it iterates over all files matching the pattern specified in between `(` and `)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following batch code:

```
pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Music\Joe Hisaishi (Classical Guitar) - Copy"
echo In directory "%cd%"
pause
for %%F in ("*.flac") do (
    echo Converting "%%F" ...
    "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\OtherApps\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%F" -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 "%%~nF.mp3"
    echo del "%%F"
)
popd
```

The main mistake is the definition of the loop variable `F` in double quotes by using `"%%F"` which is not right. The loop variable must be always defined without enclosing it in double quotes. Just on referencing the value of the loop variable in command or command block executed on each found file the double quotes should be used in case of space or `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` in file name.

It is better to use value of environment variable `USERPROFILE` instead of hard coding the folder paths with your user name. See Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

The usage of the commands `pushd` and `popd` are better to switch current directory and later restore it than using command `cd` twice.

The deletion of the converted *.flac file is not done by the batch file above because of command `echo` before for testing purposes.

But it would be possible to write this batch code without switching the current directory at all.

```
for %%F in ("%USERPROFILE%\Music\Joe Hisaishi (Classical Guitar) - Copy\*.flac") do (
    echo Converting "%%F" ...
    "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\OtherApps\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%F" -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 "%%~dpnF.mp3"
    if not errorlevel 1 del "%%F"
)
```

This batch code deletes now the *.flac file after successful conversion of the file to MP3 format.

**Note:** I don't have `ffmpeg.exe` installed and therefore don't really know if it exits with `0` on success and with a value greater `0` on an error.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`

And read also the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use

```
FOR "%F" ...
```

on the command line but

```
FOR %F ...
```

In a script you have to use `%%` instead of `%`:

```
FOR %%F ...
```

but not

```
FOR "%%F" ..
```

Same principle for `"%G"` (`"%%G"`), use `%G` (`%%G`) instead

Comment: Thanks! will using %%F instead of "%%F" in a batch file create problems if there are spaces in the filenames? if so, how do I overcome that?

Comment: if you have spaces in the filename, you can use the double quotes on the places where you will use the filename (so in the commands after the `do`) but not when declaring the loop variables. What you did inside the body of the for-loop (`"%%F"`) is good :)